# How can I write joins in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am trying to write this query in laravel

```
"SELECT DISTINCT branches.city_id, cities.title FROM branches INNER JOIN cities ON cities.id = branches.city_id WHERE company_id LIKE :id ORDER BY city_id"
```

Query that I wrote in laravel for joins is

```
App\Branch::select('branches.id','branches.title')->join('regions','regions.id','=','branches.region_id')->where('company_id', $company_id)->get()
```

It's returning the data but only `branch title` and `id`. I want other details also like `cities`, etc. I've also gotten some help from other posted question, but I was unable to understand joins.

Comment: ....  so include those columns in your select statement...

Comment: Or take advantage of the framework and use Eloquent Relationships - https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships